# Very weird issue with import

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, stashy

I'm hitting a very weird issue.

Edit: Adding full details:

```
virtualenv -p python3 testenv
cd testenv
source bin/activate
django-admin startproject blah
cd blah
mkdir modules
vi modules/stash.py
pip install django
pip install stashy
python manage.py shell < modules/stash.py
```

I have a script that sync data to populate a database:

```
$ cat modules/stash.py
import stashy
class SyncProject:
    def __init__(self, endpo, user, passw):
        import stashy
        self.stash = stashy.connect(endpo, user, passw)

access = SyncProject("http://localhost", "test", "test" )
```

I run my script with:

```
$ python  manage.py shell < modules/stash.py
```

The weirdness is that if I don't put the second `import stashy`, it doesn't work:

```
NameError: name 'stashy' is not defined
```

From the bit of Python I did a long time ago, that seems very unexpected and forces me to add import in every single method... Not sure if there is something wrong in how I import my dependencies or the way I run the script...

Edit: more details, the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/[PATH]/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/[PATH]/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/[PATH]/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/[PATH]/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/[PATH]/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
NameError: name 'stashy' is not defined
```

Comment: Firstly, fix your indentation. Secondly, post the full script; this can't be causing the problem, as nothing is instantiating your SyncProject class.

Comment: Updated with the call to SyncProject(...)

Comment: You still need to fix your indentation.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Fixed the indentation

Comment: Have you installed stashy into a virtualenv or global?

Comment: In a virtualenv

Comment: But when calling the module you have activated it?

Comment: Have you assigned a variable with name stashy before in the script?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the exception so we can see what methods are being run when it happens.

Comment: What is the line the error occurs at according to the traceback? `self.stash = stashy.connect(endpo, user, passw)`?

Comment: Added to the issue

Comment: @ffyns Could not reproduce the error. Please offer the whole code.

Comment: I added the steps I followed to create the full django app

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the behavior to [line 92](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/shell.py#L92) in the Django project: `exec(sys.stdin.read())`.

This causes your first `import stashy` to be scoped to the `Command` class. If instead the line was `exec(sys.stdin.read(),globals())` then you would not have this unexpected behavior. This change to Django would also remove the current bug/difference in behavior between code redirected to stdin and code manually typed into the Django shell/Python REPL.

Comment: Thank you internet stranger!

Comment: Trying to get the fix merged: https://github.com/django/django/pull/9464

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduce same issue at my end. I tried as per steps mentioned in question. I got the same issue.

After that I have install django==1.10. And it works. Check it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't want to start a new project with outdated dependencies